# Firefox add-on SDK - handle self signed HTTPS certificates with Request API

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to send an XMLHttpRequest through HTTPS to a server that has a self signed certificate. This is done in a Firefox add-on using the SDK's Request API.

Here is the code I use in my main.js file:

```
var Request = require("sdk/request").Request;
var xhr = Request({
  url: 'https://my-unsigned-certificate-website.com',
  onComplete: function (response) {
    console.log(response.text);
  }
});
xhr.get();
```

It fails: the webserver from my-unsigned-certificate-website.com doesn't receive any request, it seems that the failed certificate verification blocked it on the browser side. If I change the requested URL to "https://www.google.com" everything works fine.

I didn't find any information on the [Request documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request) about how to bypass the certificate check, something like "curl -k". Is there any way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Problem resolved if I navigate to https://my-unsigned-certificate-website.com and accept the security exception. Any other way to do that programmatically?

Comment: Adding an exception programmatically, without user's acknowledgment of the risks and explicit consent, would run against the concept of security.

Comment: Can't argue against that, thanks anyway.